# iphone sqlite page cache growing

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I use `sqlite` database for storage. There are many database transactions as well. My problem is that the memory usage grows rapidly for sqlite page cache. In `instruments` i could find this line

```
Graph   Category                 Live Bytes   # Living # Transient  Overall Bytes   
0       VM: SQLite page cache    12.12 MB     97       1434         191.38 MB
```

and inside it i have 97 of following files

```
#   Address     Category                Timestamp     Live  Size        Responsible Library     Responsible Caller
0   0x4c06000   VM: SQLite page cache   00:49.241.377   •   128.00 KB   libsystem_kernel.dylib  vm_allocate
1   0x5002000   VM: SQLite page cache   01:41.203.588   •   128.00 KB   libsystem_kernel.dylib  vm_allocate
2   0x5515000   VM: SQLite page cache   01:41.255.275   •   128.00 KB   libsystem_kernel.dylib  vm_allocate
3   0x5535000   VM: SQLite page cache   01:41.309.973   •   128.00 KB   libsystem_kernel.dylib  vm_allocate
4   0x5565000   VM: SQLite page cache   01:41.358.003   •   128.00 KB   libsystem_kernel.dylib  vm_allocate
5   0x55c8000   VM: SQLite page cache   01:41.407.916   •   128.00 KB   libsystem_kernel.dylib  vm_allocate
6   0x568f000   VM: SQLite page cache   01:41.451.870   •   128.00 KB   libsystem_kernel.dylib  vm_allocate
7   0x570d000   VM: SQLite page cache   01:41.501.194   •   128.00 KB   libsystem_kernel.dylib  vm_allocate
8   0x573d000   VM: SQLite page cache   01:41.550.465   •   128.00 KB   libsystem_kernel.dylib  vm_allocate
```

any idea what causes this or how to remove those files will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer, It's just a `sqlite` select method that I mistakenly put `sqlite3_close(mySqliteDB);` instead of `sqlite3_finalize(statement);`