# Websql cache size on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, memory, sencha-touch, web-sql

We've developed an app for iPad (using Sencha Touch and Phonegap) that stores data locally using websql db. 
Thousands of records are inserted in db during synchronization, but sometimes the app crashes in the middle of the process due high memory use.
Running the app, Xcode Instruments tool shows about 80mb of memory allocated by "VM: SQLite page cache". 
The question is: Is there any way to clear this "page cache", or close the connection with db? I've read some threads about pragmas for setting cache size in SQLite, but I didn't find a way to do this with websql db.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Web SQL Database Concerns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727628/html5-web-sql-database-concerns)

Comment: And also this one:

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134059/iphone-sqlite-page-cache-growing